# Как правильно реализовать связь с сервером на стороне WinForms-клиента? HttpListener или соединение ASP.NET Core и WinForm в одном проекте?

Tags: winforms, asp.net-core, rest

Помогите, никогда такого не делал(.

Надо организовать связь м/у сервером и WinForms(/WPF)-клиентами.
Нагрузка на сервер небольшая - 20 клиентов. Клиенты могут работать удалённо, а не только в ЛВС.
На сервере хранится БД + сервер получает данные от чужих сервисов и сохраняет их в БД.

Сервер - это ASP.Net Core API проект.
Сервер не просто отвечает на запросы WinForm-клиентов, но и сам может/должен информировать подключённых клиентов о событиях.

Рассматриваю Rest для взаимодействия м/у ними (Сервер-Клиенты).
Нашёл два варианта реализации на стороне WinForm:

1. HttpListener
2. Объединить ASP.NEt Core с WinForms в одном проекте -
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033762/hosting-asp-net-core-api-in-a-windows-forms-application

**Какой вариант лучше?
Вообще правильно делать так, как в (2)??**

М.быть есть другие, более лучшие(простые) варианты организации связи м/у сервером и WinForm-клиентами?

Спасибо.

Comment: Глупо не пользоваться возможностями ASP.NET. Только ради бога, не делайте на форме публичных текстбоксов и не делайте форму статическим полем! Изолируйте действия в интерфейсах и используйте внедрение зависимостей.

Comment: `Сервер не просто отвечает на запросы WinForm-клиентов, но и сам может/должен информировать подключённых клиентов о событиях.` - тогда ваш выбор - SignalR.

Comment: Всем спасибо! .